# $(-1)\otimes (-1) \cong I$

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Is there a monoidal category $\mathcal C$ whose unit object is $I$ (i.e. $I\otimes A\cong A\cong A\otimes I$ for all $A\in \text{Ob}_\mathcal C$), with an object "$-1$" such that
$$
(-1)\otimes(-1)\cong I ?
$$

*(Edit: no one misunderstood, but I'm also asking that $-1\neq I$)*

I'm struggling with that since I read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17311/categorification-of-pi) math.SE post... [Martin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1650/martin-brandenburg), if you see me, your server rejected every mail I tried to send you. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what about $\mathbb{Z}_2$ [vector spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_vector_space) over a field $k$?

$(k,0)$ is the unit in this category and $(0,k)\otimes (0,k) = (k,0)$.

Comment: Great, thanks! ...No hope to find such an object in $k-\mathbf{Vect}$, huh? In fact, it is plainly false in $\mathbf{Sets}$ with the monoidal structure induced by the product and the identity given by $\{*\}$... So I'm looking for some (counter)examples in more stuctured categories

Answer (score 1):

For any locally compact abelian group $G$, the monoidal category of continuous unitary representations of $G$ is generated by the characters $G \to \mathbb{C}$, e.g. the Pontrjagin dual group $\hat{G}$, with tensor product corresponding to the group operation and duals corresponding to the inverse (and the trivial representation corresponding to the identity).  Prometheus's example is the case $G = \hat{G} = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know almost (=some wiki stuff) anything about group representations... In particular what about my previous question (finding such an object in $k-\mathbf{Vect}$)? :( Nonetheless I can catch the whole idea, thanks!

Comment: @tetrapharmakon: you know what every object in k-Vect looks like, right?  Any category where dimension makes sense has the property that only a 1-dimensional object can have tensor square the identity, and all 1-dimensional objects in k-Vect are isomorphic.