# Proof that $\lim_{m\to\infty}(1+\frac{r}{m})^{mt}=e^{rt}$

Tags: limits, proof-writing

Can someone show me a straightforward proof that

$\lim_{m\to\infty}(1+\frac{r}{m})^{mt}=e^{rt}$

Thanks!

Comment: plug in $\tilde m = m/r$ and you're done

Comment: @Dmitri what is your definition of $e^x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\log\left(1+\frac rm\right)^{tm}=tm\,\log\left(1+\frac rm\right)=tm\,\left(\frac rm+O(\frac1{m^2})\right)=tr+O(\frac1m).
$$
So
$$
\left(1+\frac rm\right)^{tm}=e^{tr}\,e^{O(1/m)}.
$$
Taking limit, the equality follows.

Comment: I assume you meant to use "big-O", since your statement is false for "little-O".

Comment: Using $\log$ to answer this question is anachronistic. It's similar to using L'Hopital to show that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$ to show that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sin(x)=\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69825), it is shown that
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{r}{m}\right)^m=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{mr}\tag{1}
$$
Since $x\mapsto x^t$ is a continuous function, raising $(1)$ to the $t$ power yields
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{r}{m}\right)^{mt}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{mrt}\tag{2}
$$
Since $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1m\right)^m=e$ by definition, $(2)$ says
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{r}{m}\right)^{mt}=e^{rt}\tag{3}
$$