# How to get the limit of this function?

Tags: calculus, limits

How am I suppose to handle this?

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{\pi}{x}\right)^{2x}$

Comment: @Mastrem Yes, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Do you already know that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac ax\right)^x=e^a\;?$$

Comment: Duplicate: [$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{r}{x}\right)^{tx}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/244540/201168) (with $r=\pi$ and $t=2$).  (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/)*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice

$$ \left( 1 + \frac{\pi }{x} \right)^{2x} = e^{2x \ln \left( 1 + \frac{ \pi }{x} \right)}$$

and

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} 2x \ln \left( 1 + \frac{ \pi }{x} \right) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln \left( 1 + \frac{ \pi }{x} \right)}{\frac{1}{2x}} =_{\text{L'hop}} \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ \frac{ - \pi }{x(x+\pi)}}{ - \frac{1}{2x^2}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ 2 \pi x^2 }{x^2 + \pi x} = 2 \pi$$

Therefore, by the continuity of the exponential function, we have

$$ \boxed{ \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{2x \ln \left( 1 + \frac{ \pi }{x} \right)} = e^{ \lim_{x \to \infty} 2x \ln \left( 1 + \frac{ \pi }{x} \right)} = e^{2 \pi } }$$

Answer (score 3):

It holds $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{a}{x})^x = e^a$

With $(1+\frac{\pi}{x})^{2x} = \big((1+\frac{\pi}{x})^x\big)^2$ and continuity of the square function you get

$$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{\pi}{x})^{2x} = e^{2\pi}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=0.5x$:
$$\lim_{y\to\infty}(1+\dfrac{2\pi}{y})^y$$
What you can do now is say that $\frac{2y}{y}$ grows $2y$ times faster than $\frac1y$ (you can only do this when taking the limit to $\infty$):
$$\lim_{y\to\infty}(1+\dfrac{2\pi}{y})^y=\lim_{y\to\infty}(1+\dfrac{1}{y})^{2\pi y}=e^{2\pi}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(1+\frac\pi x\right)^{2x}=\left[\left(1+\frac\pi x\right)^{x}\right]^2\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\left(e^\pi\right)^2=e^{2\pi}$$

Comment: Dear DonAntonio, I'm glad to hear that. I'll erase my comment.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(1+\frac\pi x\right)^{2x}=\left(1+\frac{2\pi}{2x}\right)^{2x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}e^{2\pi}$$

($x\to\infty\iff2x\to\infty$)