# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{-5+3n}{3n}\right)^{6n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to find the limit of the following:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{-5+3n}{3n}\right)^{6n}$$

However, although I see the quite similar structure to $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$, I do not come to a meaningful result. What is the limit?

Comment: This is a standard problem  Take the log, pull out the exponent, invert the exponent to the denominator, L'hospital's, exponentiate.  Done.

Comment: Hint: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{-5+3n}{3n}\right)^{6n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 - \frac{5}{3n}\right)^{6n}$.

Comment: This would be a ridiculous problem to use l'Hôpital's.

Comment: Duplicate: [$\displaystyle\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{r}{m}\right)^{mt}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/244540/201168) ($r=-\tfrac53,t=6$). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D(1%2B%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bn%7D)%5E%7Bbn%7D%24&p=1)*)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**
Note that 
$$
\left(\frac{-5+3n}{3n}\right)^{6n}=\left(\left(1+\frac{-5/3}{n}\right)^{n}\right)^6
$$
and use the fact that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=e^x
$$
for all $x$.

Answer (score 3):

$\left\{\left(1-\frac{5}{3n}\right)^{6n}\right\}_{n\geq 2}$ is a subsequence of $\left\{\left(1-\frac{5}{n}\right)^{2n}\right\}_{n\geq 6}$ .

Since $\left(1-\frac{5}{n}\right)^n$ converges to $e^{-5}$ as $n\to +\infty$, $\left(1-\frac{5}{n}\right)^{2n}$ converges to $e^{-10}$.

Finish with: the subsequences of a converging sequence share the same limit.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: write it as follows and note that the term inside the big parenthesis has limit $e\,$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac{-3n}{5}}\right)^{\frac{-3n}{5}} \right)^{-10}$$

Answer (score 2):

The limit you recalled evaluated to $e$. Which similar one evaluates to $e^x$? That would be my hint.

### Complete solution

$$\left(\frac{-5+3n}{3n}\right)^{6n}= \left(\left(1+\frac{\frac{-5}{3}}{n}\right)^n\right)^6$$

$x^a$ is continuous for any positive $a$, hence we can switch it with $\lim$. Therefore

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{-5+3n}{3n}\right)^{6n} = \left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{\frac{-5}{3}}{n}\right)^n\right)^6 = \left(e^{\frac{-5}{3}}\right)^6 = e^{-10}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\frac{-5+3n}{3n})^{6n}$=$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{-5}{3n})^{6n}$=$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}((1+\frac{1}{\frac{3n}{-5}})^\frac{3n}{-5})^{-10}$

let  t=$\frac{3n}{-5}$,we have:

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\frac{-5+3n}{3n})^{6n}$=$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}((1+\frac{1}{t})^t)^{-10}$=$e^{-10}$

Answer (score 0):

*Another possible solution.*

Consider $$A=\left(\frac{-5+3n}{3n}\right)^{6n}\implies \log(A)=6n\log\left(1-\frac{5}{3n}\right)$$ Since $n$ is large, use Taylor series $$\log(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ Replace $x=\frac{5}{3n}$ to get $$\log\left(1-\frac{5}{3n}\right)=-\frac{5}{3 n}-\frac{25}{18 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right))$$ $$\log(A)=-10-\frac{25}{3 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Now, use Taylor again $$A=e^{\log(A)}=\frac{1}{e^{10}}-\frac{25}{3 e^{10} n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.