# How to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+...\frac{1}{n!}) = e$ with $x_n = (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, integral-inequality

I'm very confused about the question below, which I couldn't figure out for days.

In Example 5 the author is teaching us proving

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...\frac{1}{n!}) = e$$

with equation

$$x_n = (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$$
$$y_n = 1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...\frac{1}{n!}$$

I'm thinking $x_n < e$ if we take $e$ is the special value only $n$ tends to infinity, and term by term comparing tells us $x_n \le y_n$ if we consider $n$ can be $1$, then we have the following:
$x_n \le  y_n, x_n < e$, but I believe that doesn't give us $e\le    y_n$.
I think only if we use $x_n = e$ and with $x_n \le   y_n$ brings us $e \le   y_n$. So I'm quite confused how did him resulted $e \le    e$ first?

Then $m < n$ is implemented to help us go further, with $x_m < x_n < e$ and resulting $y_m\le   e$? How?
I'm thinking such outcomes only come from $x_m \le  y_m$ and $x_m < x_n \le  e$.

I really need your help.

Page url:
[Calculus With Analytic Geometry By George Simmons](https://archive.org/details/calculuswithanalyticgeometrybygeorgesimmonszlib.org/page/n457/mode/2up?view=theater)

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69806/prove-the-definitions-of-e-to-be-equivalent) answer your question?

Comment: First you must tell us your definition of $e$. For instance, some people define $e$ as the limit as $n$ tends to infinity of $1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...\frac{1}{n!}$. But then your question would answer itself!

Comment: The definition of e is this: $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$

Comment: See this application of [Tannery’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem#Example).

Comment: Thank you but are they any intuitive approach understanding such a proving process?    The [Tannery’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem#Example) is harder for me without understanding many base knowledge.

Comment: Expanding $x_{n}$ using binomial theorem for any index and taking the limit of $n$ as it tends to infinity gives $y_{n}$ I think.

Comment: [My lecture notes on the exponential function](https://users.utu.fi/lahtonen/Exp.pdf) have a proof for this. I did it for the sake of completeness, because the same concern occurred to me, also. The catch is that those lecture notes are in Finnish. The proof you want is that of *Lause 0.6.*, straddling pages 4 and 5. The ingredients I use: A) the binomial theorem, B) definition of $\exp(x)=\sum_{n}x^n/n!$, C) the functional equation $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$, D) the definition 
$$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac1n)^n.$$

Comment: Thank you for your comments, to @AAM, the expanding of $x_n$ will give you extra terms $(1-\frac{1}{n})*(1-\frac{2}{n})...$, which will make $x_n <= y_n$.

Comment: Thank you very much @JyrkiLahtonen, the equation in page 5, how could we for sure that 

"when $n > k > 0$ and $n$ tends to infinity will swipe the $-i$ influence which goes from 0 to k"?

Cause I'm thinking as each term multiplied a term which is less than 1 before read your note

Comment: @John On top of page 5 I fix $k$ (for a few lines), and then let $n\to\infty$. Then for all $i$ in the range $0<i\le k$ we have $(n-i)/n\to1$, and arrive at a lower bound
$$e\ge\sum_{i=0}^k\frac1{i!}$$ that holds first for this fixed value of $k$, but because the choice was arbitrary it holds for all $k$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry I put many confusing comments here before. How about page 4 last equation, the value $k$ made $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\ge\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{1\cdot(1-\frac{1}{n})\cdots(1-\frac{k-1}{n})}{k!}$? Why its $\ge$ sign instead of just a $>$ sign?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n.$By the binomial theorem, we have

$x_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1\cdot(1-\frac{1}{n})\cdots(1-\frac{k-1}{n})}{k!}$

Find an integer $m$ such that $m<n$,there is

$x_n>\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{1\cdot(1-\frac{1}{n})\cdots(1-\frac{k-1}{n})}{k!}$

Let $n\rightarrow \infty$,then $\mathrm{e}\geq \sum_{k=0}^m\frac{1}{k!}$.Similarly, let $m\rightarrow \infty$,we can get $\mathrm{e}\geq \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}$

On the other hand,

$x_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1\cdot(1-\frac{1}{n})\cdots(1-\frac{k-1}{n})}{k!}\leq\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}$

Let $n\rightarrow \infty$ ,we get $\mathrm{e}\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}$.Hence , by the sandwich theorem,we have

$\mathrm{e}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}$

Comment: Thank you very much @RainField, I was following the pdf note above and couldn't let it go. I saw the similarity of both answers, and I guess its standard procedure in Mathematical analysis, but why can we step further from $m < n$ with $n\to\infty$ to $m\to\infty$?

Comment: For the expansion of $x_n$, we can see the limit of numerator is $1$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$. Then the rest of fraction is $\frac{1}{k!}$,which is what we want.But as you can see, when we let $n\rightarrow\infty$, the number of items  also increases to infty, which isn't what we want. So we hope that we can control the number of items, that's the reason why $m$ appears.

Comment: May I ask why its $\geq$ sign instead of $>$ sign in $\mathrm{e}\geq \sum_{k=0}^m\frac{1}{k!}$?

Comment: Because it's not sure whether you can get $\lim a_n> \lim b_n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ from $a_n>b_n$.For example,$\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: Thank you, so $\mathrm{e}\geq \sum_{k=0}^m\frac{1}{k!}$ is based on 1) the possibility that $m = n-1$ and 2) the $n\to \infty$ gives us $1\cdot(1-\frac{1}{n})\cdots(1-\frac{k-1}{n}) \to 1$, and that's where $m$ comes to help. Thank you very much