# Famous real analysis limit proof

Tags: real-analysis

$$\lim_{n \to\infty }\sum_{k=0}^n {1 \over k!}=e$$
Which is the proof for the limit listed above?I know its a famous limit,but i cant figure out how to solve it(I'm a 12th grader).

Comment: Not really an answer but: some people define $e$ as that series, in which case all  you must do is show the series converges. Otherwise you have another definition of $e$, perhaps as $e=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+1/n)^n$, in which case you have to show both limits converge and are actually equal.

Comment: More concisely: **what is your definition of $e$**?

Comment: the euler constant

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1054175/215011; see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54448/combinatorial-proof and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69806/prove-the-definitions-of-e-to-be-equivalent

Comment: Okay, this might be hard to understand since you (quite likely) haven't been through university-level mathematics yet, and I could probably write a novel about this. When you ask for a "proof," you have to start from **something** and prove theorems from that **something**. "The Euler constant" is not a mathematical definition. For example, you could define $e$ as the number $e$ such that $\ln(e) = 1$ (but then I'd have to ask, how do you define $\ln$?). Or you could define $e$ as that limit that @LoveTooNap29 stated.

Comment: The point is, you need to give us a **mathematical** definition to work from before we can even do anything.

Comment: Hi Razvan,  Following this web site's custom, I posted (right now) a complete answer to your question IN THE OLD THREAD, referenced at the top of this page. Please take a look there and let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the classical definition of e, $e = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n  $ and the binomial theorem.
\begin{align}
e &= \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 + n \frac{1}{n} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!} \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}\frac{1}{n^3} + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!}\frac{1}{n^4} + \cdots\\
\end{align}
Using the linearity of the limit and the fact that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n - k  + 1)}{k! n^k} &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{n}\cdot \frac{n - 1}{n} \cdot \frac{n - 2}{n} \cdots \frac{n - k + 1}{n} \frac{1}{k!}\\
&= \frac{1}{k!}
\end{align}
Using this result with each term of the series yields
\begin{align}
e &= \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 + n \frac{1}{n} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!} \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}\frac{1}{n^3} + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!}\frac{1}{n^4} + \cdots\\
&= 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{4!} + \cdots\\
&= \sum^\infty_{k = 0} \frac{1}{k!}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^n_{k = 0} \frac{1}{k!}
\end{align}

Comment: This is an excellent 18th century "proof" and should be quite interesting for a 12th grader.  When you escape (as you must) from the 12th grade you will question whether these operations can be justified.