# let $e$= lim$ (1+1/n)^n$ prove that $e= 1/0!+1/1!+1/2!+1/3!+...$ using induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $e=2.17...$ be defined as $$ e = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$$ .Prove that $$e= \frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\ldots$$
>   using induction
>
> hint: $(a+b)^n$ can be expanded using binomial thm and use
>   $${n \choose{k}}+ {n \choose{ k-1}} = {n+1 \choose k}$$

I can show this using taylor expansion of e^x, but my professor wants me to use the hint. I expanded (1+1/n)^n using binomial thm, but have no idea what is the next step. I can't even use the hint :(
I see there are duplicate questions but my professor wants us to use the hint! Any ideas?
any suggestion or hint is welcomed! Thanks

Comment: Correction:  $e=2.71\dots$

Comment: Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054175/why-does-the-sum-of-the-reciprocals-of-factorials-converge-to-e) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54448/combinatorial-proof/54499#54499) question.