# Better understanding proof of e^x

Tags: real-analysis

I came across [this nice answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1758228/) on stack:

[image]

However, two things still bother me. First, why do we assume a function that equals its own derivative will take the form of $a_nx^n$? Why should it be an exponential function? I can understand the reason for the sigma a little, it implies a function immune to derivatives should work regardless of the input changing from $0$ to infinity (why not negative infinity as well?)

Second, the condition $f(0) = 1$ also bothers me. So assuming we determine the function will be exponential in some way, I'm guessing this is a necessary condition as all exponential will be $1$ when using $0$ as input. Or is there something more to it?

Comment: We're assuming that there exists some function that admits a  power series.

Comment: Thanks! How do we make that assumption however? Could there be another function that could equal its own derivative for example, which is not exponential?

Comment: There could be another function, but that's not part of the assumption.

Comment: We *don't* assume it takes the form of $A_n*x^n$ which not an exponential function. (An exponential function is $b^x$, not $x^n$).  We assume that $f(x)$ takes a form of an *infinite* sum of power values.  In other words a power series.  We can assume this, because if it is its own derivative it is infinitely differentiable and that is just it's Taylor series.

Comment: Thanks that's much more clear.

Comment: If it's a stackexchange answer you are citing, you should link it rather than (or as well as) screen-shotting it.

Comment: @space, probably https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054175/why-does-the-sum-of-the-reciprocals-of-factorials-converge-to-e/1758228#1758228