# Exponential equality

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

How do I can prove that
$$e\ :=\ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\ =\ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j!},$$
without use of derivatives?

Comment: This has already been answered as a special case of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/54499/13854) ($x=1$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have the equality
$$(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)}{k!}x^k$$
hence for $x=\frac{1}{n}$ and $\alpha=n$ we have
$$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}\frac{1}{n^k}$$
and then
\begin{array} \lim\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}\frac{1}{n^k}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}\frac{1}{n^k}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}.\end{array}
**Added**  let's denote by
$$f_k(n)=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}\frac{1}{n^k},$$
and since for all $k$ we have
$$0\leq\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{n^k}\leq 1$$ then $||f_k||_\infty\leq \frac{1}{k!}$ and then the series $\sum_k f_k(n)$ is uniformy convergent for $n$ since the series $\sum_k||f_k||_\infty$ is convergent and this  justify the permutation $\lim\sum=\sum\lim$

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Binomial Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for this. Applying the definition gives:

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = \sum_{k \ge 0} \left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ k \end{array}\right)\frac{1}{x^k}$$

where the [generalised binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series) are given by:

$$\left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ k \end{array}\right) = \frac{x(x-1)\ldots(x-k+1)}{k!}$$

Putting this together, we have:

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{x(x-1)\ldots(x-k+1)}{k!}\frac{1}{x^k}$$

The key thing here is: what happens as $x \to \infty$? The generalised binomial coefficient is an order $k$ polynomial in $x$. We then divide by $x^k$, so we have something of the form

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{x^k+O(x^{k-1})}{x^k}\frac{1}{k!}$$

Where $O(x^{k-1})$ means something of order $k-1$ in $x$. Hopefully, you can see that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^k+O(x^{k-1})}{x^k} = 1$$

It follows that:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = \sum_{k \ge 0}\frac{1}{k!}$$

Of course, it doesn't take much more to show that

$$\operatorname{e}^t = \lim_{x \to 0}\left(1+\frac{t}{x}\right)^x = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{t^k}{k!}$$

Comment: So, for the Binomial Series, I have: $$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \sum_{j=0}^n{n \choose j}\frac{1}{n^j} \leq \sum_{j=0}^n\frac{1}{j!},$$ but how do I can obtain the other inequality? Thanx

Comment: @ShanaKugimiya There's no need for inequalities. I've written a full reply above. All you really need to be able to do is find the limit of a polynomial divided by a polynomial.