# Evaluating: $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{{6}/{x^{2}}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

I am trying to evaluate the following but without result.

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{{6}/{x^{2}}}$$

Can you please give me some hints? I have tried to put log to both sides but it hasn't lead me somewhere... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write it as $$\left[\left(1+\dfrac{\sin(x)-x}{x}\right)^{\dfrac{x}{\sin(x)-x}}\right]^{\dfrac{6(\sin(x)-x)}{x^3}}.$$

Notice what was done is to add $1$ and subtract $1$ in the base of the exponential, and then tweak the exponent, to make it look like $\big(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\big)\large^n$ inside the big brackets.

The part inside the brackets goes to $e$. So, you have to compute the limit of $\dfrac{6(\sin(x)-x)}{x^3}$

**General strategy:**

This is an indeterminate limit of the form $1^\infty$. You can approach these indeterminate forms in the following two ways:

1. Take the $a^b$ and write it as $\left[(1+(a-1))^{\dfrac{1}{a-1}}\right]^{\large(a-1)b}$ The part in brackets tends to $e$. So, you only need to resolve the indeterminate form $(a-1)b$. Since this is an indeterminate of the product it could be solved by applying L'Hospital to $\dfrac{a-1}{1/b}$.
2. Take the $a^b$ and write it as $e^{b\ln(a)}$ and then you only need to resolve the indeterminate form of the product $b\ln(a)$. Which could also be approached by L'Hospital to $\dfrac{\ln(a)}{1/b}$.

The two are essentially the same. The only difference might be that in one you get a logarithm in what remains to be computed and in the other you don't.

Answer (score 7):

Just know that

$$\log{\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right)} \sim \log{\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}\right)} \sim -\frac{x^2}{6}$$

Comment: @darkchampionz: That is precisely the point of my answer.  The log sinc piece becomes $-x^2/6$.  Then when you multiply by $6/x^2$, the log of your limit becomes $-1$.  Exponentiate both sides to get your limit.

Answer (score 1):

**You have:**
$$\lim_{x\to0} \bigg(\frac{\sin x}{x}\bigg)^{6/x^2}$$

---

We know that
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$
(this can be proved by writing the Taylor's Expansion of $\sin x$);

and that
$$\frac{6}{x^2} \to\infty$$

So your problem is in the form of $(\to1)^{(\to\infty)}$.
Whenever we reach a situation like the one above, we do the following steps:

If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)}$, where $f(x)\to1$ and $g(x)\to\infty$, the value of the limit is:

> $$\Large e^{g(x)(f(x)-1)}$$

---

**PROOF:**

$$\Large \lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)}\\$$
$$\Large = \lim_{x\to a} e^{\ln f(x)^{g(x)}}$$
$$\Large = \lim_{x\to a} e^{g(x).\ln f(x)}$$
(...using logarithmic properties)

The index part is getting very tiny and squeezed up making it difficult to read - which is why I'm only solving the index below:

\begin{eqnarray}
Let L &=& g(x).\ln f(x)\\
 &=& g(x).\ln(1 + f(x) - 1)\\
 &=& g(x).\frac{\ln\bigg(1 + \big(f(x) - 1\big)\bigg)}{\big(f(x) - 1\big)}.(f(x) - 1)\\
\end{eqnarray}
We know that $f(x) - 1 \to0$ $(\because f(x) \to1)$; and that:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1 + x)}{x} = 1$$

So we get:
$$L =\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)\cdot(f(x) - 1)$$

Hence, your limit is:

$$\Large e^\left({\lim\limits_{x\to 0} g(x)\cdot(f(x) - 1)}\right)$$

Now, substituting the values for your functions, your limit is:

$${\Large e^\left({\lim\limits_{x\to 0}6\dfrac{\sin x-x}{x^3}}\right)}$$

Comment: Surely for this method to work you need to do if the limit exists in the first place?

Comment: How can the limit result in functions?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff   The question is in the form of $f(x)^{g(x)}$ where $f(x) \to1$ and $g(x) \to\infty$. Since the value of this is $e^{g(x)(f(x)-1)}$, we need to substitute the values; which will ultimately give us $e^{6\frac{(\sin x - x)}{x^3}}.$ Now the limit needs to be solved.

Comment: See, the answer even tallies with @RGB's.

Comment: @AndrewD I don't understand what you mean. :/

Comment: @mikhailcazi Ah, I see my sentence doesn't make much sense - what I mean is that what you have shown is that if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)^{g(x)}$ exists then it is equal to a certain value; however, I don't believe there is anything here which actually shows that the original limit exists (which we need before we can find its value in the manner you have done).

Comment: @AndrewD You mean $f(0)$ may not be equal to $f(0^{-})$ and $f(0^{+})$? Well in the "Proof" section, I've solved it all step-by-step. If we go by solely that manner, after putting the values we'll automatically get to know if the limit exists or not.

Comment: @mikhailcazi No, I mean that we don't know that the original limit exists; your method appears to assume its existance in order to show that it is equal to a certain value - this is fine provided the limit exists. Just because we get a finite value from your calculations isn't enough to tell us whether we actually have a limit (for example, if $1+x+x^2 + \cdots$ converges to a limit, then the limit is $(1-x)^{-1}$, but for $x=2$, just because we get a value of $-1$ it doesn't mean the series actually converges to it)

Comment: @AndrewD I don't get your point, I'm sorry. I've just rearranged the original expression - to get $e^{\frac{6(sin x - x)}{x^3}}$. If you see, RGB's done the same thing - albeit in a different manner. After that, we all know that the limit of $\frac{(sin x - x)}{x^3}$ exists (and is equal to $1/6$, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @mikhailcazi Ah, I see now - I thought you had called the original limit L - apologies!

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean @mikhailcazi, but don't leave the limit operator out!

Comment: See my edit. Do you agree with it? I change $e^{(\cdot)}$ to $\exp(\cdot)$ to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

The best hint I can give, I think, is not to give up if an idea doesn't immediately solve the problem for you.

If
$$ L = \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{{6}/{x^{2}}}$$
then
$$ \log L = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{6 \log\left(\frac{\sin x}{x} \right)}{x^2} $$

Now forget for a moment that you're trying to find $\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{{6}/{x^{2}}}$. You have a new problem to see if you can solve:

> Evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{6 \log\left(\frac{\sin x}{x} \right)}{x^2} $$

What is the *form* of this limit? What methods do you have for solving limits of such a form?

Answer (score 0):

### Easy trick

$$\lim_{x\to 0} (\frac{\sin x}{x})^{\frac6{x^2}}  =\lim_{x\to 0}\exp\left(\frac{6}{x^2}\ln\left(\frac{\sin x -x}{x}+1\right)\right) \color{blue}{\sim \lim_{x\to 0}\exp\left(\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}\right)}{\frac{x^2}{6}}\right)= e^{-1}}$$

Given that $$\sin x -x \sim -\frac{x^3}{6}~~~~and ~~~~ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\ln\left(1-h\right)}{h} = -1$$