# Value of $\lim\limits_{z \to 0}\bigl(\frac{\sin z}{z}\bigr)^{1/z^2}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

Find the value of $$\lim\limits_{z \to 0}\left(\dfrac{\sin z}{z}\right)^{1/z^2}$$

So I took a log: $$\frac{1}{z^2}\log\left(\frac{\sin z}z\right)$$ If I could expand it something like $\log(1+x)$ .. any hints ?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447312/evaluating-lim-limits-x-to0-left-frac-sin-xx-right6-x2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choosing the usual branch for the complex logarithm, and keeping $\;z\;$ close to zero in the complex plane, we get

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\text{Log}\,\frac{\sin z}z}{z^2}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\frac{z\cos z-\sin z}{z\sin z}}{2z}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z\cos z-\sin z}{2z^2\sin z}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=$$

$$=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\cos z-z\sin z-\cos z}{4z\sin z+2z^2\cos z}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{-\sin z-z\cos z}{4\sin z+8z\cos z-2z^2\sin z}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=$$

$$=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{-2\cos z+z\sin z}{12\cos z-12z\sin z-2z^2\cos z}=-\frac1{6}$$

Complete the exercise now.

Comment: Thanks for writing this in a math for dummies style...

Answer (score 6):

Using the Maclaurin series for $\sin$, we have

$$\frac{\sin(z)}{z} = \frac{z-\frac{z^3}{6}+o \left ( z^3 \right )}{z} = 1-\frac{z^2}{6}+o\left ( z^2 \right ).$$

Using the most common Taylor series for $\ln$, we have

$$\ln(1+z)=z+o(z).$$

Combining these we get

$$\frac{1}{z^2} \ln \left ( \frac{\sin(z)}{z} \right ) = \frac{1}{z^2} \left ( -\frac{z^2}{6} + o(z^2) \right ) = -\frac{1}{6} + o(1).$$

I think you can take it from here. An approach without using series would have been to use L'Hopital's rule a couple times, though this would have involved some ugly algebra.

Comment: Could you point me to a place where I can read about this o(z)...

Comment: @square_one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation Alternately, I can define it for you using this problem as an example. $o(f(z))$ is a symbol for an unspecified function which satisfies $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{o(f(z))}{f(z)} = 0$. So for example, the statement $\sin(z) = z-\frac{z^3}{6} + o \left ( z^3 \right )$ means $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\sin(z)-z+\frac{z^3}{6}}{z^3} = 0$. (Technically the limiting value of $z$ is implicit from context in most cases.)

Comment: Thanks .. I saw this in a data structures course ...

Comment: @square_one Big O, little o, and Big Theta notation are common in computer science. Usually there the limit which is implicit from context is as the size of the problem (usually denoted by $n$) tends to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You were in the good track. Starting with $$A=\left(\dfrac{\sin z}{z}\right)^{1/z^2}$$ $$\log(A)=\frac{1}{z^2}\log\left(\frac{\sin z}z\right)$$ Now, as Ian did, use the Taylor expansion $$\sin(z)=z-\frac{z^3}{6}+\frac{z^5}{120}-\frac{z^7}{5040}+O\left(z^8\right)$$ $$\frac{\sin z}z=1-\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{z^4}{120}-\frac{z^6}{5040}+O\left(z^7\right)$$ Now, consider $$\log(1-y)=-y-\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{y^3}{3}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ and use $$y=\frac{z^2}{6}-\frac{z^4}{120}+\frac{z^6}{5040}$$ and arrive to $$\log\left(\frac{\sin z}z\right)=-\frac{z^2}{6}-\frac{z^4}{180}-\frac{z^6}{2835}+O\left(z^8\right)$$ $$\log(A)=-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{z^2}{180}-\frac{z^4}{2835}+O\left(z^6\right)$$ that is to say $$A=e^{-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{z^2}{180}-\frac{z^4}{2835}+\cdots}=e^{-\frac{1}{6}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{30}-\frac{2z^4}{945}}$$ Use that $$e^y=1+y+\frac{y^2}{2}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ and replace $$y=-\frac{z^2}{30}-\frac{2z^4}{945}$$ and you should finally arrive to $$A=e^{-\frac{1}{6}}\Big(1-\frac{z^2}{180}-\frac{17 z^4}{50400}+\cdots\Big)$$ which also shows how the limit is approached.

If you plot the original function and the last approximation on the same graph, you will probably be amazed to see how close are the curves for $-\frac {\pi}2 \leq x \leq\frac {\pi}2$.

Answer (score -5):

$\sin{z}=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-......$

Therefore, we have

$\lim_{z \to 0}({\frac{\sin{z}}{z}})^{1/z^2}=\lim_{z \to 0}(\frac{z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-......}{Z})^{1/z^2}$

=$\lim_{z \to 0}(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-......)^{1/z^2}$

=$(\lim_{z \to 0}(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-......))^{1/z^2}$ (the limit of expression inside the bracket is taken)

This gives:

$(1-\frac{0^2}{3!}+\frac{0^4}{5!}-......))^{1/z^2}=1^{1/z^2}=\underline{1}$

Comment: -1, because this is simply incorrect. The actual answer is $e^{-1/6}$. Even when taking this limit over the reals, you are dealing with an indeterminate form $1^\infty$, so this kind of reasoning is not valid.

Comment: I see how much pleasure doing this fills you.

Comment: @sholaOtitoju Some of us don't usually downvote, but your answer is dead wrong, that's for sure. It is rather worrying that someone doing a doctorate in mathematical engineering  (whatever this is) and "loving to teach maths" can do such a huge mistake in such basic stuff as you did in your answer and **still** claim that his answer is the correct one and all the other ones are wrong. Please do check *again* your notes in basic infinitesimal calculus.

Comment: Shola, there are 2 answers that are different to yours. Are you sure that your anwer is correct?

Comment: @shola, honestly: please *do check* your notes or ask someone knowing basic mathematics, and stop embarrassing yourself. This is my honest advice to you. Now you do whatever you want.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong. I checked with calculator and it looks like the other answers.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+z+to+0+%28%28sin+z%29%2Fz%29^1%2Fz^2

Comment: @Timbuc he is embarrassing Mechanical Engineers too which I take offence since I have MS in ME. If you are an "engineer" (sceptical here), you should know how to use Matlab, Python, Mathematica, C, or some language. I suggest that you use one of these programs to see that your answer is wrong.

Comment: I certainly made a mistake. All this while I was solving $(\frac{\sin{z}}{z})^{1/z}$ instead of $(\frac{\sin{z}}{z})^{1/z^2}$. I just discovered the error in my calculations.

Comment: @sholaOtitoju Ok, but **still** the way you made your mistake is wrong and not only the result: it's wrong to take the limit *only* of part of the expression and leave part of it unresolved (your fifth line) and it's wrong also to deduce that $\;1^{1/z}=1\;$ or $\;1^{1/z^2}=1\;$ . Anwyay, good you finally realized this. My advice now is to delete your answer.