# Find limit of $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\sin z}{z}\right)^{1/z^{2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

where $z$ is a complex number. Please help me to solve it. I have no idea how to solve this but I have little bit knowledge of limits. my textbook's answer is $e^{-1/6}$. I am very confused at this. Should I solve it by taking log?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447312/evaluating-lim-limits-x-to0-left-frac-sin-xx-right6-x2

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may use the Taylor series expansions, as $z \to 0$,
$$
\sin z=z-\frac{z^3}6+O(z^5)
$$ and, as $u \to 0$,
$$
\log(1+u)=u-\frac{u^2}2+O(u^3)
$$ giving

> $$
> \lim_{z \to 0}\left(\frac{\sin z}{z}\right)^{1/z^{2}}=\lim_{z \to 0}e^{\large \frac1{z^2}\log\left(1-\frac{z^2}6+O(z^2)\right)}=\lim_{z \to 0}e^{\large -\frac16+O(z^3)}= e^{\large -\frac16}.
> $$

Comment: I got it thank u sir

Comment: @MichaelHardy Typo edited. Thank you.

Comment: A comment on which branch of $\log$ you're using should be included. Also, you have errors in your last line.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\sin z}{z}\right)^{1/z^{2}}=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}e^{1/z^{2}\ln(\frac{\sin z}{z})}$$

$$\frac{\sin z}{z}=1-\frac{z^2}{6}+o(z^2)$$

$$\ln(1-\frac{z^2}{6}+o(z^2))=-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{z^2}{48}+o(z^2)$$

$$e^{1/z^{2}\ln(\frac{\sin z}{z})}=e^{-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{z^2}{48}+o(z^2)}$$

Finally : 
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\sin z}{z}\right)^{1/z^{2}}=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}e^{-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{z^2}{48}+o(z^2)}=e^{-\frac{1}{6}}$$