# Approximate the logarithm of any base

Tags: logarithms

I'm currently in the process of approximating the logarithm of any base. I know that $\ln(x)$ or $\log_e(x)$ can be approximated with this formula:

$$\ln(x)=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{2k+1}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{2k + 1}$$

<sup>This was taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Calculation).</sup>

However, I can't seem to find any approximation for any other base.

Is there any approximation that can approximate a number where a number and a base is given?

Comment: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogDeBruijn

Comment: See the answers at this 2013 thread: [Natural logarithms base $e$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420177/natural-logarithms-base-e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y:=\log_ax$ then $x=a^y=e^{y\ln a}$, so $y=\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}$.

Comment: More a comment than an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that

$$\log_b x = \frac{\log_e x}{\log_e b},$$ you're left to get an approximation of $\log_e b$ which you can do using the formula you provide in the question.

Comment: More a comment than an answer...

Comment: @JeanMarie I agree. I feel the questioner is hoping for an infinite summation that deals explicitly with the base b rather than just doing a standard conversion. Wish I knew how!