# What is the limit of the sequence $ (\frac{3-4n}{1+n})(1+\frac1n)^n $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to find the limit of the sequence 
$$
\left(\frac{3-4n}{1+n}\right)\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n
$$
I am aware that if one sequence converges and another sequence converges then the multiplication of two sequences also converge. The limit of the first sequence is $-4$. However I do not know how to calculate the limit of the second sequence.

Comment: What is n tending to?

Comment: @Robinb97 n is tending towards infinity. Apologies, I forgot to put that up

Comment: It can be done with Maple. See [the screen](http://rapidshare.com/files/3989611251/limit.docx) from RapidShare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach
$$ \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}=e^{ n \ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) } = e^{ n (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+\dots) } = e^{1-\frac{1}{2n}+\dots}\underset{\infty}{\longrightarrow} e $$

Comment: @ MhenniBenghorbal Thank you for your help. So would the final limit of the entire product be -4e?

Comment: @Anonaanon: Yes.

Answer (score 2):

This is [the constant known as $e$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29). In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54499), it is shown to be equal to
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}\tag{1}
$$
In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245), Bernoulli's Inequality is used to show that
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\tag{2}
$$
is an increasing sequence and that
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}\tag{3}
$$
is a decreasing sequence. Thus, $e$ is greater than any term in $(2)$ and less than any term in $(3)$.

$n=1$ in $(2)$ shows that $e\ge2$ and $n=5$ in $(3)$ shows that $e\lt3$.