# Showing two sequences converge and have the same limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Show that the sequences $$x_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\quad\text{and}\quad y_n=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$ are convergent and have the same limit.

I do not know how to show that either of these are bounded sequences, but they are both pretty clearly monotone.

Comment: Both converge to $e$ but for different reasons.. I'd tackle each one disregarding the other. Are you familiar with Taylor expansions?

Comment: If you are capable to interpret german mathematics, the lengthy calculation is at (http://www2.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~llehmann/Ma4Ph/Ana-I-WS05/zahl_e.pdf). Should at least give enough hints.

Comment: yeah i cant read that :(

Comment: @Dror yes I am, but wolfram says the first one converges to some weird thing:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k+%3D+0+to+n+of+%281%2F%28k!%29%29

Comment: This isn't a trivial thing to do. See [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEIQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcazelais.disted.camosun.bc.ca%2F250%2Fe-definition.pdf&ei=YeMHU8vSCO_KsQSIg4DICA&usg=AFQjCNGHzHbBc2um1zSjt3VOIh0TN1SE5w&bvm=bv.61725948,d.cWc&cad=rja) for one proof.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k+%3D+0+to+Infinity++of+%281%2F%28k%21%29%29

Comment: @DavidMitra wouldn't it be better/easier to evaluate each separately ?

Comment: Wolfram gives you the finite sum with n+1 terms, you want the limit of it when n goes to infinity (that is, the limit of the infinite series) :) see Dror pointer.

Comment: @DavidMitra

it's sum from k = 0 to n, not k = 0 to infinity though

Comment: @terribleatmath the *limit* of the sum as $n$ tends to $\infty$ is what you want. i.e, the *series*

Comment: oh okay, sorry for that mixup, it's a bit confusing. then it is definitely e as you said :)

Comment: [Knock yourself out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Equivalence_of_the_characterizations).

Comment: @Dror I have shown that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is bounded above by $2^n$. is this enough to show that the sequence is "bounded"?

Comment: @terribleatmath Nope. $2^n \rightarrow \infty$..

Comment: -_-

here is what my logic was

$0 < \frac{1}{n} \leq 1$, so $1 < (1+\frac{1}{n}) \leq 2$ and thus $1 < (1+\frac{1}{n})^n \leq 2^n$

Comment: @Dror was I on the right track above?

Comment: @terribleatmath I'm not sure.. The easiest way to show $a_n = (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ converges is to show that $\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+k}} \rightarrow 1$ for all $k$, then writing the definition, and arriving at the http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyCriterion.html

Comment: ah so you think I should show it is a cauchy sequence.

How did you pull out this $\large\frac{a_n}{a_{n+k}}$ argument? I dont understand that piece.

Comment: @terribleatmath try to toy around with it, but I take back the "easiest" part in the comment... BTW, you have *everything* you need in the link by David Mitra above...!

Comment: I have proved more generally that ${\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \dfrac{x}{n}\right)^{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\dfrac{x^{k}}{k!}}$ at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/637687/72031 Your question is about $ x = 1$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh that is way above my level.

Comment: Ok I have tried to put a simplified version for $x = 1$ as an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have provided a link to an answer (of a more general question) in the comments, it would be better to give you the main ideas related to your specific question.

Note that the sequence $x_{n}$ is actually the $n$-th partial sum of a series which is convergent (easily proved via ratio test). Another approach to proving that $x_{n}$ converges is to show that it increases as $n$ increases and is bounded. Clearly as $n$ increase the number of terms in sum defining $x_{n}$ increases and hence the sequence $x_{n}$ increases. Again we can see that if $n > 2$ then $$\begin{aligned}x_{n} &= 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n!}\\
&\leq 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n - 1}}\\
&= 1 + \dfrac{1 - \dfrac{1}{2^{n}}}{1 - \dfrac{1}{2}}\text{ (sum of a finite GP)}\\
&\leq 1 + \dfrac{1}{1 - \dfrac{1}{2}} = 3\end{aligned}$$ Hence $x_{n}$ is bounded and therefore $x_{n}$ tends to a limit.

Next we can focus on $y_{n}$. Clearly if $n > 3$ then we can see that $$\begin{aligned}y_{n} &= \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\\
&= 1 + n\cdot\frac{1}{n} + \frac{n(n - 1)}{2!}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2} + \cdots + \text{ (upto }n\text{ terms)}\\
&= 1 + 1 + \dfrac{1 - \dfrac{1}{n}}{2!} + \dfrac{\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - \dfrac{2}{n}\right)}{3!} + \cdots\end{aligned}$$

Now it is easy to see that as $n$ increases number of terms in the above expression increases as well as each term of the above sum also increases. It follows that $y_{n}$ increases as $n$ increases. Again we can note that $$\begin{aligned}y_{n} &= 1 + 1 + \dfrac{1 - \dfrac{1}{n}}{2!} + \dfrac{\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - \dfrac{2}{n}\right)}{3!} + \cdots\\
&\leq 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n!}\\
&= x_{n} \leq 3 \text{ (as proved before)}\end{aligned}$$ therefore $y_{n}$ is also bounded and $\lim_{n \to \infty}y_{n}$ also exists.

Also we have seen above that $y_{n} \leq x_{n}$ so that $\lim_{n \to \infty}y_{n} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n}$. To establish equality we need to bound $x_{n}$ by another sequence. That sequence is given by $z_{n} = (1 - (1/n))^{-n}$. Clearly using general binomial theorem we have $$\begin{aligned}z_{n} &= 1 + n\cdot\frac{1}{n} + \frac{n(n + 1)}{2!}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2} + \cdots\\
&= 1 + 1 + \dfrac{1 + \dfrac{1}{n}}{2!} + \dfrac{\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 + \dfrac{2}{n}\right)}{3!} + \cdots\\
&\geq 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n!} = x_{n}\end{aligned}$$ and thus we finally arrive at $$y_{n} \leq x_{n} \leq z_{n}$$ The next thing is to show that both $y_{n}$ and $z_{n}$ tend to same limit as $n \to \infty$ and then by Squeeze theorem $x_{n}$ would also tend to same limit. To proceed further we can note that $$\begin{aligned}\frac{y_{n}}{z_{n}} &= \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n}\\
&= 1 - n\cdot\frac{1}{n^{2}} + \frac{n(n - 1)}{2!}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{2} - \cdots + \text{ (upto }n\text{ terms)}\\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{n} + \dfrac{1 - \dfrac{1}{n}}{2!}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2} - \cdots\\
&= 1 - \phi(n)\end{aligned}$$ where the function $\phi(n)$ is a finite sum defined by $$\phi(n) = \frac{1}{n} - \dfrac{1 - \dfrac{1}{n}}{2!}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2} + \dfrac{\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - \dfrac{2}{n}\right)}{3!}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3}- \cdots + $$ Now we can estimate $\phi(n)$ as $$\begin{aligned}0\leq|\phi(n)| &\leq \frac{1}{n} + \dfrac{1 - \dfrac{1}{n}}{2!}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2} + \dfrac{\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - \dfrac{2}{n}\right)}{3!}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3} + \cdots\\
&\leq \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{2!}\cdot\frac{1}{n^{2}} + \cdots\\
&\leq \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{2n^{2}} + \frac{1}{2^{2}n^{3}} + \cdots\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\left(1 + \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{(2n)^{2}} + \cdots\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\cdot\dfrac{1 - \dfrac{1}{(2n)^{n}}}{1 - \dfrac{1}{2n}}\\
&\leq \frac{1}{n}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1 - \dfrac{1}{2n}} \to 0\text{ (as }n \to \infty)\end{aligned}$$

It follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\phi(n) = 0$ and hence $\lim_{n \to \infty}y_{n}/z_{n} = 1$ and hence $\lim_{n \to \infty}y_{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}z_{n}$.

Comment: You are a genius, I would not be able to come up with something like this on my own, thank you.

Comment: I am bit flattered by your appreciation, but to be frank there are many users in this website who deserve much more appreciation than me. I do know some stuff and I know them well enough. Thats all I can say.

Comment: I have simplified the last past related to equality of limit of $y_{n}, z_{n}$ so that my earlier linked answer is no longer needed.

Comment: I dunno man, you seem like an extremely intelligent person who really knows his stuff. That is admirable and deserves respect. I am just barely passing undergrad.

Comment: By the way I can let you in on my secret of knowing such things well enough. Try to find the book "A Course of Pure Mathematics" 10th edition by G. H. Hardy. Most of what I have learnt comes from this book.

Comment: One book? that's impressive that you could learn so much from just that.

Comment: There are many other books too but the best is from G H Hardy. A list of my favorite 7-8 books is available at http://paramanands.blogspot.in/p/bibliography.html

Answer (score 1):

For $k \ge 2,k! > 2^{k-1}$ so
$$\frac{1}{k!} \le \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$

i.e. terms of the first sum are all (after a while) bounded by 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 +  ... = 1.

Comment: my problem with proofs like this is this i guess: how do i know that just presenting something like this is "rigorous" enough?

Comment: hey, i think there is an error in your post: the first line should read

$k! > 2^{k-1}$, not $2^k$