# Prove that $1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\dots+\frac{x^n}{n!}<e^x$ for all $x\in(0,\infty),n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

Intuitively this makes sense but I don't know how to formally show that this is true. I tried using induction but that got me nowhere .

Comment: How are you defining $e^x$? If it's just as a power series, you might as well subtract the left from the right and look at what you get.

Comment: The question is only interesting if your definition of the exponential does not depend directly on the power series. For example:
$$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$$
For this definition, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637255/prove-that-the-limit-definition-of-the-exponential-function-implies-its-infinite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$x > 0 \implies \frac{x^k}{k!} > 0 \ \ \forall k$$
It then follows that:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} < \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \frac{x^k}{k!} < \cdots < \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!} = e^x$$

Answer (score 7):

If we officially do not yet know about Taylor series, we can use induction. First we prove the base case, that $1\lt e^x$ for all $x\gt 0$. Let $f(x)=e^x-1$. Then $f(0)=0$, and $f'(x)=e^x\gt 0$ for all $x$. So $f(x)$ is increasing on our interval, and therefore $f(x)\gt 0$ for all positive $x$.

Now suppose that we know that for a particular $k$ we have
$$1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots +\frac{x^k}{k!}\lt e^x\tag{1}$$
for all positive $x$. We want to show that
$$1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots +\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\lt e^x\tag{2}$$
for all positive $x$. Let
$$f(x)=e^x-\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots +\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\right).$$
Note that $f(0)=0$, and that 
$$f'(x)=e^x-\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots +\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\right).$$
By (1), $f'(x)\gt 0$ for all $x$, so $f$ is increasing. This shows that for $x\gt 0$ the inequality (2) holds.

Answer (score 2):

This is a truncated Taylor expansion of $e^x$,  and the series has all positive terms, so truncating it automatically gets you a smaller sum than the total.

Answer (score 1):

The induction method.

$n=1$ is trivial.

Assume it holds for $n, (n\geq 1)$.

Then for $n+1$, we put 
$$f(x)=e^x-\left(1+x+\dots+\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right)$$
By assumption, $f'(x)=e^x-(1+x+\dots+\frac{x^{n}}{n!})>0\Rightarrow f(x)>f(0)=0$ for $x>0$

Thus, it also holds for $n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily solved once recognizing the finite sum as a partial sum of the series that defines $e^x$