# Proving the limit definition of derivative of $e^x$ using the squeeze theorem?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

My friend and I were working to see if we could use the squeeze theorem to prove that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$.

We said that by definition, the derivative is

$$\frac{d}{dx} e^x =\lim \limits_{h\to0} \frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h} = \lim \limits_{h\to0} \frac{e^{x}(e^h-1)}{h} =  \lim \limits_{h\to0} e^x *\lim \limits_{h\to0} \frac{(e^h-1)}{h}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}h+1 \leq \frac{(e^h-1)}{h} \leq |h| + e^h$$

$$\lim \limits_{h\to0} \frac{1}{2}h+1 = \lim \limits_{h\to0} |h| + e^h = 1$$

$$\lim \limits_{h\to0} e^x *\lim \limits_{h\to0} \frac{(e^h-1)}{h} = \lim \limits_{h\to0} e^x = e^x$$

However, this seems more simplified than any other proof we've seen, so we're wondering if there's a fault here. Neither of us have taken analysis yet, so we might be assuming something incorrect.

Comment: Where did $\frac{1}{2}h+1 \leq \frac{(e^h-1)}{h} \leq |h| + e^h$ come from?

Comment: @Henry ah sorry I should've specified, we wanted to bound above and below and we came up with those functions to do so.

Comment: What is your definition of $e$?

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah I suppose it's the traditional definition of $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} (1+1/x)^x$.

Comment: A complete proof would need to show why these are bounds

Comment: @Henry assuming we did prove these bounds, would the proof be rigorous and correct?

Comment: If anyone suggests l'Hopitals rule Im coming after you.

Comment: Why do you need to prove it in this way? I know proofs that circumvent this approach.  You can use the chain rule and the derivative of the natural logarithm to prove this rule, and those two rules can be proven separately too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty nice way to do this is as follows:

Note that $$|e^h - 1 - h| = \left|\frac{h^2}{2} + \frac{h^3}{6} + \frac{h^4}{24} +...\right|  $$ $$ = h^2 \left|\frac{1}{2} + \frac{h}{6} + \frac{h^2}{24} +...\right|\leq h^2 \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + ... \right) = h^2$$

So if $h\neq 0$, we have $\left|\frac{e^h - 1}{h} - 1 \right| \leq |h|$, i.e. $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{e^h - 1}{h} - 1\right) = 0$$

Note that this tells us that $e^x$ is differentiable at the origin with derivative 1.

Now: $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{e^{x+h} - e^x}{h}\right) = e^x \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^h - 1}{h} = e^x$$

as required.

Comment: Thank you, except doesn’t this require knowing the derivative of $e^x$ in order to create this Maclaurin expansion? Unless I suppose you define $e$ to be that series.

Comment: Not if you *define* $e^x$ by the power series. Even if you use the sequence definition as you wrote in the comments, you can easily show this is equivalent to the series representation of $e^x$

Comment: I could show that it's equal to $\lim \limits_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^x$ easily?

Comment: Yes. It is a standard argument in elementary real analysis. For example, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637255/prove-that-the-limit-definition-of-the-exponential-function-implies-its-infinite

Answer (score 4):

Here is  a pure squeeze theorem proof without using a Taylor expansion and using the definition $e = \lim_{n \to \infty}(1 +1/n)^n$.

For $h > 0$, let $n = \lfloor1/h\rfloor$. We have $n \leqslant 1/h < n+1$ and

$$\frac{n}{n+1}(n+1)(e^{1/n+1} - 1)=  n(e^{1/n+1} - 1 ) \leqslant \frac{e^h -1 }{h} \leqslant (n+1)(e^{1/n} -1) = \frac{n+1}{n}n(e^{1/n}-1).$$

Since $n \to \infty$ iff $h \to 0$ we obtain the limit $1$ by the squeeze theorem if we can show that $n(e^{1/n} - 1) \to 1$.

This follows from the inequality

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n < e < \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1},$$

which implies

$$1 < n(e^{1/n}-1) < n\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{1/n}\left( 1+ \frac{1}{n}\right)-1  \right] \leqslant 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

Here we used Bernoullis's inequality $(1 + 1/n)^{1/n} < 1 + 1/n^2$ to obtain the far right inequality. A second application of the squeeze theorem gives us $n(e^{1/n}-1) \to 1$.

If $h <0$ and the limit is approached from the left we can use the above result and

$$\frac{e^h -1}{h} = \frac{e^{-|h|}-1}{-|h|} = e^{-|h|}\frac{e^{|h|}-1}{|h|},$$

since $e^{-|h|} \to 1$ as $h \to 0$.

Comment: The second squeeze application can be simplified with $e<(1+\tfrac{1}{n-1})^n$.

Answer (score 1):

How did you get these inequalities ?

$$\frac{1}{2}h+1 \leq \frac{(e^h-1)}{h} \leq |h| + e^h$$

You need to prove these inequalities to have a valid proof.

You can not use Taylor Series because your statement is used in Taylor series.

Comment: Mohammad, thank you for your answer. I understand why we can't use the Taylor Series. I don't see exactly where in our proof we use the series expansion.

Comment: My point is that in proving the inequalities you can not use the Taylor series.

Answer (score 0):

**Claim 1:** $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\ln(x+1)}{x}=1$

Proof: by properties of log, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\ln(x+1)}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \ln[(x+1)^{1/x}]=\ln(e)=1$.

**Claim 2:** $\lim\limits_{y\to0}\dfrac{e^y-1}{y}=1$

Proof: putting $x=e^y-1$ then $\lim\limits_{y\to0}\dfrac{e^y-1}{y}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{x}{\ln(x+1)}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\ln(x+1)}{x}}=\dfrac{1}{1}=1$

With this, $$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}=e^x$$