# trying to prove: $0<\left|e-S_{n}\right|<\frac{3}{(n+1)!} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to  prove that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}
 $  this inequality holds:

$0<\left|e-S_{n}\right|<\frac{3}{(n+1)!}
 $

S.T:  $S_{n}=1+1+\frac{1}{2!}+\dots+\frac{1}{n!}
 $

By induction:

assuming for $n$ and proving for $n+1$:

$\left|e-S_{n+1}\right|=\left|e-S_{n}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\right|=\left|(e-S_{n})+(-\frac{1}{(n+1)!})\right|<|e-S_{n}|+\left|-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\right|<\frac{3}{(n+1)!}+\left|-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\right|
 $

but how can i continue from this stage?

edit note:
i can't use the fact that:
$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_{n}=e
 $

thank you.

Comment: This using of the triangle inequality doesn't seem me efficient because your estimation will be greater than $\frac{3}{(n+1)!}$. Instead of that use the following equality: $$e - S_n =\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+ \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + \frac{1}{(n+3)!}+\, \ldots$$

Comment: first of all thank you for the comment, but i can't use the fact that:
$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_{n}=e
 $

Comment: State in the question your definition of $e$ and what you are allowed to use, if there are limitations.

Comment: Okay, but please, define $e$. I usually define it as the limit of that sum XD There are a lot of possible ways of definition that number.

Comment: Can you use the remainder form of Taylor's Theorem in your proof?

Comment: lol i know, but in this stage  this limit is yet proved.
 just this one:
$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}=e
 $

Comment: yes, i can use the reminder of taylor in my proof!

Comment: Consider the $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} (S_n - (1+\frac{1}{k})^k)$ and use the binomial theorem. You'll get my suggested equation.

Comment: @Amit then there is a value a such that 0<a<1 for which the remainder term is $\frac{e^a}{(n+1)!}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
(n+1)!\,(e-S_n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+k)!}\\
&\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(n+2)^{k-1}}\\
&=\frac{n+2}{n+1}
\end{align}
$$

---

Doing this without the series representation seems difficult. We could use [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54499) to show that
$$
\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right]^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}
$$

Comment: This answer begs the question, imo...and also the OP said he can't use the series definition of $\;e\;$ .

Comment: Ah, I see that now. We could use [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/54499) to show the series representation from the definition they have. I would be very interested in another approach using that definition.

Comment: problem solved, with using the  remainder form of Taylor's Theorem. thank you very much all!

Comment: @Amit Isn't "the Taylor Theorem" *exactly* the same as the series representation for $\;e\;$ ?

Comment: Generation of the Taylor series would need the definition of $e^x$ that says it is its own derivative. This also makes  $e^x$ monotonic increasing. A bound on the remainder term then requires that e<3, which can also be obtained from the Taylor series (first 3 terms should do it probably).